# IntelliJ how to use Form Designer?

Tags: forms, intellij-idea

Im new at IntelliJ and I want to use the Form Designer. If I place a button for example it will expand all the way left and right. I can't change the size and I can't move it where I want to. If I change the Layout Manager it won't work. With WindowBuilder everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use control (e.g. button) properties, like **Horizontal/Vertical Align** to set the position, relative to the surrounding area. Use **HSpacer/VSpacer** to adjust the control position.

Comment: Why is this more complicated than the eclipse windowbuilder?